# The function is replacing the entire list with y when its only suppose to swap values equal to z

Tags: elisp

```el
(defun replace (L z y)
  (let ((f (lambda (x)
             (if (equal x z)
                 y x) z y)))
    (mapcar f L)))



(replace '(3 1 5 6 3 2 3) 3 9)
(9 9 9 9 9 9 9)
```

Comment: n.b. I wanted to reformat the `if` expression over more lines, but doing that makes the problem so obvious that the question becomes redundant.  That's a good take-away, though -- if you format your code more verbosely, and let Emacs indent it, such problems become visually apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lambda` always returns `y`, since you have a `z` and a `y` after your `if`. Change it to drop those and then it works:

```
(defun replace (L z y)
  (let ((f (lambda (x)
             (if (equal x z)
                 y
               x))))
    (mapcar f L)))

(replace '(3 1 5 6 3 2 3) 3 9)
(9 1 5 6 9 2 9)
```